# How to solve this error in C - cannot convert 'disciplina*' to 'restaurant*' in assignment

Tags: c

I try to replace in the previous code the word **discipline** to **restaurant** and as a result I get an error.

`20 8   C:\Users\path\restaurant.cpp    [Error] cannot convert 'restaurant*' to 'disciplina*' in assignment`
`46 2   C:\path\restaurant.cpp  [Error] cannot convert 'disciplina*' to 'restaurant*' in assignment`

there is code:
https://github.com/Auritar/Cproject

Answer (score 2):

In your restaurant.h, you forgot to change

```
struct disciplina *next;
```

to

```
struct restaurant *next;
```